# Expected spies not being called on an inner function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm writing an app with AngularJS. I am writing unit tests for my angular service with karma and jasmine. It's not working as expected as the unit tests keep giving me these errors:

> Expected spy photo to have been called.

Here is my codepen with the bug: https://codepen.io/aubz/pen/zXyvbj

Here is a code snippet of my unit test:

```
  it('should process the plain clocking settings', function () {

    ClockingRecordTypeFactory.getRecord('plain', 'here', null, null, null, null, null);

    spyOn(ClockingRecordTypeFactory, 'plain').and.callFake(function () {});
    spyOn(ClockingRecordTypeFactory, 'photo').and.callFake(function () {});
    spyOn(ClockingRecordTypeFactory, 'geo').and.callFake(function () {});
    spyOn(ClockingRecordTypeFactory, 'manual').and.callFake(function () {});

    expect(ClockingRecordTypeFactory.plain).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(ClockingRecordTypeFactory.photo).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(ClockingRecordTypeFactory.geo).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(ClockingRecordTypeFactory.manual).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

});
```

and of the function I am trying to test:

```
function getRecord(type, origin, coords, imageData, comments, reason, date) {

    var record = getBaseClockingRecord();

    if (type === 'plain') {
        plain(record);
    }

    if (type === 'photo') {
        photo(record);
    }

    if (type === 'geo') {
        geo(record, coords);
    }

    if (type === 'manual') {
        manual(record);
    }

    return record;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test is spying on `ClockingRecordTypeFactory.plain` but actually the `getRecord` function calls the local function `plain` so the spy will not be called at all.

You can make the spies work as intended by changing `getRecord` like this:

```
if (type === 'plain') {
    this.plain(record);
}

if (type === 'photo') {
    this.photo(record);
}

if (type === 'geo') {
    this.geo(record, coords);
}

if (type === 'manual') {
    this.manual(record);
}
```

Also you need to set up your spies at the start of the test before calling `getRecord`:

```
spyOn(ClockingRecordTypeFactory, 'plain').and.callFake(function () {});
spyOn(ClockingRecordTypeFactory, 'photo').and.callFake(function () {});
spyOn(ClockingRecordTypeFactory, 'geo').and.callFake(function () {});
spyOn(ClockingRecordTypeFactory, 'manual').and.callFake(function () {});

ClockingRecordTypeFactory.getRecord('plain', 'here', null, null, null, null, null);
```

[Updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gyZWXe)